# Bing Maps REST API Basic key returns different results than Enterprise key

Tags: bing-maps

This unstructured format

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine=3712%20Adelaide&adminDistrict=TX&locality=The%20Colony&countryRegion=US&postalCode=75056&maxRes=1&key=YourKey
```

does not seem to return the same result as this structured format

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/US/TX/75056/The%20Colony/3712%20Adelaide?o=json&key=YourKey
```

The structured format is returning high confidence and the unstructured format is returning medium.  What am I missing?

Edit: I never would have expected this.  I have discovered the unstructured format returns medium confidence with my current API key and returns high confidence with a new trial key.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the response from the Microsoft Bing Team:

*Issue Definition: Question regarding Bing Maps REST Location API service. Scope Agreement: As per our communication, you provided a query for 3712 Adelaide, The Colony, TX 75056 with the Bing Maps REST Location API with a Basic and Enterprise key and received different results and you would like to know the reason. The reason you are receiving different results is because we are in the middle of deploying new information to the Bing Maps REST geocoder. This information is first flighted on Basic (free) accounts before it is released to Enterprise customers.
Our Product Group let us know that it should be deployed to all Enterprise customers by the end of this month.*

Comment: You didn't mention you where using different keys.

Comment: A colleague supplied the original link with his trial key and I compared it with the link generated with my code and our enterprise key. I posted the edit as soon as I realized the key was the difference.  I apologize for the inadvertent misdirection.  I hope this post will help educate others about this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the URL's you provided I see the exact same results with the same high confidence value.